# UE4 - Visual Studio cannot open any source file after I add new c++ files from Editor - UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM error

Tags: c++, include, unreal-engine4

I started a c++ project in UE4.25 days ago, and started prototyping in blueprints.
Now I wanted to start and take my logic to c++.

**Problem:** As soon as I created a new Actor from the Editor (right-click -> new c++), the new file generated *thousands* of errors engine-related, and could not find source files anymore. It could compile, but then I couldn't work on it, because it was full of squiggly lines and I couldn't get IntelliSense to work even on basic types as FVectors.

**What I tried:** I tried manually adding UE paths to the project settings; I tried deleting and changing the Actor's name; Rebuilt every time.
Uninstalling and reinstalling UE4.25 actually changed something: There were now just 10 errors instead of 10000, and they all were about **missing source files** (starting from CoreMinimal.h).
I tried again with every solution I found on the internet because why not, but no luck.

I am now uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio as well. Has anyone encountered this kind of error? Is there any new solution?

**EDIT:** Reinstalling Visual Studio didn't help. I get errors about 'cannot open source file' UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM CriticalSection.h" PlatformCompilerPreSetup.h" PlatformCompilerSetup.h" PlatformAtomics.h" PlatformMath.h" PlatformMemory.h" PlatformMisc.h" PlatformProcess.h" PlatformProperties.h" PlatformString.h" PlatformTime.h" PlatformTLS.h and then 13345 other errors not about includes.

Answer (score 5):

Find the file of type "uproject" in your project folder, right-click the file, select "Generate Visual Studio project files", and return to the IDE after completion, you will be prompted to modify the file, choose to reload all After completion, regenerate the project solution.

Comment: With this method, I also recommend trying to delete the intermediate/saved/binaries folders prior to regeneration of project files.